# SQL query in JOIN condition

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM header 
   INNER JOIN co ON header.Subject = co.Subject 
   INNER JOIN signature ON header.Subject = signature.Subject 
   INNER JOIN q2 ON header.Subject = q2.Subject 
   INNER JOIN q1 ON header.Subject = q1.Subject 
WHERE header.Branch = 'BIOM' AND header.Semester='VIII' 
   AND header.Subject='II' AND co.Subject='II' 
   AND signature.Subject='II' AND q1.Subject='II' AND q2.Subject='II';
```

I tried this query to join my 5 tables, I got the result but it repeats 4 times. Please help to me resolve this problem.

Comment: you should give some information about tables.about their columns.for example ,is there more than records in tables with the sam subject is one table?

Answer (score 1):

#How to solve the problem:
To resolve the actual issue with your code you will have to redo the database schema that you are using. Currently, you have a single table that connects all other tables. This is causing a cartesian product to happen because there is no other relationship between the tables except for that one main table. Because there is only one table that links all those table together SQL does not know how to combine the data into a single table and as a result the cartesian product table gets created which contains combinations of the data from the tables.

#Quick fix:
Whenever you want to get unique data you want to use the `distinct` keyword. This will eliminate rows that have the exact same data from the resulting table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM header 
   INNER JOIN co ON header.Subject = co.Subject 
   INNER JOIN signature ON header.Subject = signature.Subject 
   INNER JOIN q2 ON header.Subject = q2.Subject 
   INNER JOIN q1 ON header.Subject = q1.Subject 
WHERE header.Branch = 'BIOM' AND header.Semester='VIII' 
   AND header.Subject='II' AND co.Subject='II' 
   AND signature.Subject='II' AND q1.Subject='II' AND q2.Subject='II';
```

Also in your `where` clause you don't need all those `and` statements because you have already joined the tables.

This will produce the same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM header 
   INNER JOIN co ON header.Subject = co.Subject 
   INNER JOIN signature ON header.Subject = signature.Subject 
   INNER JOIN q2 ON header.Subject = q2.Subject 
   INNER JOIN q1 ON header.Subject = q1.Subject 
WHERE header.Branch = 'BIOM' AND header.Semester='VIII' 
   AND header.Subject='II';
```

Comment: Please educate people as to why their query has a cartesian product that is multiplying the number of rows, rather than just saying "mehh.. whack DISTINCT in there.. It'll be fine!". Next thing you know the question will be "My query was returning a million duplicate records, so I just whacked DISTINCT in there like the man on the internet told me, but now it crashes my production system. ps; the query is called 100 times a second in a live stock trading app"

Comment: @CaiusJard I completely agree. Your comment made my day! I corrected my answer. I hope that I explained it correctly.

Comment: I'd personally go a bit more into detail on why cartesian products occur, btw

Comment: @CaiusJard I updated my answer. I hope that it is better now.

Comment: Tysm @bhristov. I have used this method but still, it is showing me same problem in the output

Comment: @TARIQSHAIKH could you please post your schema design?